# Android Media Player Update UI components upon onCompletion()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-music-player

I am doing a music player. Where I use a musicService binded to multiple activities. I want the activity to be notified when current song is finished and next song starts playing so I can update the title, artist, cover art accordingly.

I tried to override the `onCompletion()` function for every activity, but it always messed up when switching between activities.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: You mean 'MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.onCompletion()`? If it is, try to 'runOnUIThread' or 'Handler' for each activities.

Comment: I don't know exactly meaning 'messed up'. I think you tried to change UI views at 'onCompletion()' but it doesn't work, right?